# Installing and Running GLPK

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to do some simple linear programming problems, and from what I gather, GLPK is a good tool.

Problem is, I am COMPLETELY lost on how to download/install/run this!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

Search the repository to find the package:

```
sudo apt-cache search "glpk"
```

choose your relevant packages and install them using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install package1 package2
```

for case of the OP:

```
sudo apt-get install glpk-utils libglpk-dev glpk-doc python-glpk
```

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install python-glpk
sudo apt-get install glpk-utils
```

Comment: @Ken Do you need more info?